# ASP.NET Core: Accessing appsettings from another project in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In my `Startup.cs` class I have the following config build which initializes the db context:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json",true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

Configuration = builder.Build();

NHibernateUnitOfWork.Init(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:OracleConnection"]);
```

`NHibernateUnitOfWork` is located in a different project as a class library project. I want to be able to inject (or somehow pass the settings) instead of using the `NHibernateUnitOfWork.Init` in my `Startup.cs` class.

I can build the appsettings in my class library but trying to avoid that.

What is a sane way to do this ?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080695/access-net-core-configuration-class-from-another-assembly

Answer (score 5):

You can inject it.

In your `Startup.cs` class, you can add the following to your `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method:

```
services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
```

From there, you can use constructor injection and consume it downstream the same way you normally would:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(IConfigurationRoot configuration) 
    {
        NHibernateUnitOfWork.Init(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:OracleConnection"]);
    }
}
```

NOTE:  This assumes `Configuration` is defined in your `Startup.cs` class:

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:
[Read appsettings json values in .NET Core Test Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791634/read-appsettings-json-values-in-net-core-test-project)

Essentially this is an integration solution using the TestServer. But if you're having to use the configuration, then it should probably be an integration test anyway.

The key to using the config in your main project inside your test project is the following:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "copyToOutput": {
    "include": [ "appsettings.Development.json" ]
  }
}
```

which needs to go inside your main project's *project.json*