# Read appsettings json values in .NET Core Test Project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, appsettings

My Web application needs to read the Document DB keys from appsettings.json file. I have created a class with the key names and reading the Config section in `ConfigureServices()` as:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
    services.AddSession();
    Helpers.GetConfigurationSettings(services, Configuration);
    DIBuilder.AddDependency(services, Configuration);
}
```

I'm looking for the ways to read the Key values in Test project.

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#configuration

Answer (score 213):

This is based on the blog post *[Using Configuration files in .NET Core Unit Test Projects](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-configuration-files-in-dotnet-core-unit-tests/)* (written for .NET Core 1.0).

1. Create (or copy) the appsettings.test.json in the Integration test project root directory, and in properties specify "Build Action" as Content and "Copy if newer" to Output Directory. Note that it’s better to have file name (e.g. `appsettings.test.json` ) different from normal `appsettings.json`, because it is possible that a file from the main project override the file from the test project, if the same name will be used.
2. Include the JSON Configuration file NuGet package (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json) if it's not included yet.
3. In the test project create a method,

   ```
    public static IConfiguration InitConfiguration()
            {
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json")
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables() 
                    .Build();
                    return config;
            }
   ```

AddEnvironmentVariables (suggested in [@RickStrahl blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Feb/18/Accessing-Configuration-in-NET-Core-Test-Projects) ) is useful if you want to pass some secrets, that you prefer not store in appsettings.test.json

4. Use the configuration as usual

   ```
    var config = InitConfiguration();
    var clientId = config["CLIENT_ID"]
   ```

BTW: You also may be interesting in reading the configuration into the IOptions class as described in *[Integration test with IOptions<> in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649045/integration-test-with-ioptions-in-net-core)*:

```
var options = config.Get<MySettings>();
```

Comment: config.Get<MySettings>() returns empty value. You should use IOptions like this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019988/servicecollection-returns-null-for-ioptions-even-though-getsection-is-working

Comment: applies to Net 6 MSTest project in VS 2022 ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, yes, we are using this approach in .Net 6 MsTest projects. I didn’t look if anything better exist in more recent versions.

Answer (score 46):

**Add the configuration file**

First, add a appconfig.json file to the Integration test project

**Configure the appconfig.json file to be copied to the output
directory by updating**

[image]

**Add NuGet package**

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

**Use the configuration in your unit tests**

```
[TestClass]
public class IntegrationTests
{
    public IntegrationTests()
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appconfig.json").Build();
        
        _numberOfPumps = Convert.ToInt32(config["NumberOfPumps"]);

        _numberOfMessages = Convert.ToInt32(config["NumberOfMessages"]);

        _databaseUrl = config["DatabaseUrlAddress"];
    }
}
```

Comment: valid for NET 6 using Section: (builder.Configuration.GetSection( and IOptions?

Comment: Step 1b: Make sure json file's properties are set to: *Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always*

Comment: Is there a way to get appsettings.Developlent.json from webApi project inside of appsettings.json?

Answer (score 26):

Suderson's solution worked for me when modified as below:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    IConfiguration config = builder.Build();

    //Now, You can use config.GetSection(key) to get the config entries
```

Answer (score 6):

For ASP.NET Core 2.x projects, copy the `appsettings.json` file to the build dir automatically:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\MyProj\appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: This works and VS is smart enough to know that it's the same file. Of course, any edits you make to your 'test' version will be replicated into the server version, since it's the same file.

Comment: I like this solution. In my implementation I copied the appsettings.development.json as I don't want to be messing with the real deal in a test project. Better than manually copying everytime you need to update the file!

Answer (score 4):

Copy the `appSettings.json` to your Test project root directory and mark its property as *Content* and *Copy if newer*.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
  .AddEnvironmentVariables();
ConfigurationManager.Configuration = builder.Build();
```

`ConfigurationManager` is a class and it has a static property `Configuration`. This way the whole application can just access it as `ConfigurationManager.Configuration[<key>]`

Comment: First half is right. Using static ConfigurationManager.Configuration doesn't sound correct.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [Artem answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62248513/2250792), but using an embedded resource (as stream):

```
Stream configStream =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.AppName.Test.appsettings.test.json");

IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonStream(configStream)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

[image]

Comment: a great picture that helped me after 3 hours of frustration.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to read configuration from a stream rather than from a file. That gives more flexibility because you can create a light weight test setup without committing multiple json configuration files:

```
public static class ConfigurationHelper
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"Root\":{\"Section\": { ... }}");
        using var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonStream(stream)
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `project.json` from you test project, add the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.0.0",
  "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
  "BancoSentencas": "1.0.0-*"
},
```

`BancoSentencas` is the project I want to test. The other packages are from xUnit and the TestHost that will be our in-memory server.

Include also this build option for the appsettings.json:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "copyToOutput": {
    "include": [ "appsettings.Development.json" ]
  }
}
```

In my test project, I have the following test class:

```
  public class ClasseControllerTeste : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture> {

    public ClasseControllerTeste(TestServerFixture fixture) {
      Fixture = fixture;
    }

    protected TestServerFixture Fixture { get; private set; }


    [Fact]
    public async void TestarRecuperarClassePorId() {
      using(var client = Fixture.Client) {
        var request = await Fixture.MyHttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/classe/1436");
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        string obj = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ClasseModel classe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClasseModel>(obj);
        Assert.NotNull(classe);
        Assert.Equal(1436, classe.Id);
      }
    }
  }
```

And I also have the TestServerFixture class that will configure the in-memory server:

```
  public class TestServerFixture : IDisposable {
    private TestServer testServer;
    protected TestServer TestServer {
      get {
        if (testServer == null)
          testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseEnvironment("Development").UseStartup<Startup>());
        return testServer;
      }
    }

    protected SetCookieHeaderValue Cookie { get; set; }

    public HttpClient Client {
      get {
        return TestServer.CreateClient();
      }
    }

    public async Task<HttpRequestMessage> MyHttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod method, string requestUri) {      
      ...
      login stuff...
      ...
      Cookie = SetCookieHeaderValue.Parse(response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie").First());

      var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri);

      request.Headers.Add("Cookie", new CookieHeaderValue(Cookie.Name, Cookie.Value).ToString());
      request.Headers.Accept.ParseAdd("text/xml");
      request.Headers.AcceptCharset.ParseAdd("utf-8");
      return request;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
      if (testServer != null) {
        testServer.Dispose();
        testServer = null;
      }
    }
  }
```

That's how I test my project. I use the Startup.cs from the main project, and I create a copy from the appsettings.json in my test project (appsettings.Development.json)

Comment: What's this TestServer? Your custom class?

Comment: It's a class from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` package. Are you using xUnit? I'm gonna edit my answer and provide more details.

Comment: Yeah. I'm also using xUnit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code. My application is not a Web API. So help me how can I test it?

Comment: So, you app is a MVC, right? Do you want to test your MVC Controller?

Comment: You can use the same code and pass the URL from your MVC Controller. Replace the '/api/classe/1436' for '/home/youraction'. If you're action return a view, then you need this view in your test project too. But I would not test a view this way.

Comment: Another answer that ignores the question :(

Comment: Need help? The answer shows how to use app.settings in the test project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WebApplicationFactory` [to create a test server for integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests) and you already have a way to get at config values in your server-side controllers (you probably do!), then you can just re-use this (and get at any other injected items you need) in your integration tests, as follows:

```cs
// Your test fixtures would be subclasses of this
public class IntegrationTestBase : IDisposable
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
    protected readonly HttpClient _client;

    // The same config class which would be injected into your server-side controllers
    protected readonly IMyConfigService _myConfigService;

    // Constructor (called by subclasses)
    protected IntegrationTestBase()
    {
        // this can refer to the actual live Startup class!
        _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
        _client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // fetch some useful objects from the injection service
        _myConfigService = (IMyConfigService)_factory.Server.Host.Services.GetService(typeof(IMyConfigService));
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        _client.Dispose();
        _factory.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Note that you do not need to copy over `appsettings.json` in this case, you're automatically using the same `appsettings.json` which the (test) server is using.

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm using the same method you suggested. But I have to override some settings, I couldn't find a way to make that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, That does make sense. I only need my integration test settings to be the same as my development settings. I think `appsettings.json` only supports Development, Production and Staging, so if you need a fourth variant for Test, I am not sure. I suspect there would be a way to inject some extra config (as I think all config is searched in order) that would override what you need.

Answer (score -5):

Honestly, if you are *unit testing* an application, you should try to isolate the class you are testing from all dependencies, like calling other classes, accessing file system, database, network etc. Unless you are doing integration testing or functional testing.

Having that said, to unit test the application, you probably want to *mock* these values from your appsettings.json file, and just test your logic.

So your `appsettings.json` would look like this.

```
"DocumentDb": {
    "Key": "key1" 
}
```

Then create a settings class.

```
public class DocumentDbSettings
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

Then register it in `ConfigureServices()` method.

```
services.Configure<DocumentDbSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb"));
```

Then for example your controller/class could look like this.

```
// ...
private readonly DocumentDbSettings _settings;

public HomeController(IOptions<DocumentDbSettings> settings)
{
    _settings = settings.Value;
}
// ...
public string TestMe()
{
    return $"processed_{_settings.Key}";
}
```

Then in your tests project you can create such unit test class.

```
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestMe_KeyShouldBeEqual_WhenKeyIsKey1()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string expectedValue = "processed_key1";
        var configMock = Substitute.For<IOptions<DocumentDbSettings>>();
        configMock.Value.Returns(new DocumentDbSettings
        {
            Key = "key1" // Mocking the value from your config
        });

        var c = new HomeController(configMock);

        // Act
        var result = c.TestMe();

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expectedValue, result);
    }
}
```

I used NSubstitute v2.0.0-rc for mocking.

Comment: Yeah but... what if I'm doing integration tests? You completely failed to answer the actual question