# .NET Core xUnit project not recognising app.config or appsettings.json

Tags: .net, .net-core, xunit, appsettings

I have a .NET Core Web API project which already has an appsettings.json file, but I want to add the same thing to my corresponding xUnit project.

I added an appsettings.json file in the root of the project [image: project files]

And the contents of the appsettings.json is

```
{
    "DatabaseType" : "MySql",
    "ConnectionStrings" : {
    "CycleTrackingDb": "connection_string_here"
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is when I call `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CycleTrackingDB"]` and `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseType"]` it comes back as NULL or an empty string.

I set up xUnit using the Class Fixtures section of the xUnit guide https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html

In my DatabaseFixture is this

```
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public Context Context { get; private set; }

    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        Context = new Context(DatabaseOptionsFactory.DbContextOptions);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

All my test classes will inherit from this one:

```
[Collection("Database collection")]
public class CycleTargetTrackerTest
{
    protected Context Context { get; }

    public CycleTargetTrackerTest()
    {
        Context = new DatabaseFixture().Context;
    }
}
```

The DatabaseOptionsFactory is just a static class that should read in the settings of the appsettings.json file, with the first 2 lines of the static constructor being the following, which will use the output to set up the context

```
var databaseType = (DatabaseType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DatabaseType), Config.Configuration.Settings["DatabaseType"]);
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CycleTrackingDB"];
```

These both return empty.

**EDIT**
I managed to get it to read in the appsettings.json file. I followed this guide here: [Read appsettings json values in .NET Core Test Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791634/read-appsettings-json-values-in-net-core-test-project), but now what I'd like to do is load the settings in the same way as `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain how you launch tests?

Comment: Amended my question to include test setup

Comment: What is 'same way as System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager'? It's load automatically?

Comment: Apologies, I guess what I meant was convert the connections strings section to a ConnectionStringsSection, I realise there's not a way to do this, and if I did want to do this I'd load the settings into custom settings section classes. It does load now, though so it does work