# Configurations in Core xUnit Test Project: The configuration file 'appsettings.test.json' was not found

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to create my first unit test project in .NET Core.  I need to figure out how to get the `appsettings.json` configurations into this project.

Following the highest voted response here: [Read appsettings json values in .NET Core Test Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791634/read-appsettings-json-values-in-net-core-test-project)

I did the following:

1) Copied the `appsettings.json` file from the main project into the unit test project root folder and re-named it `appsettings.test.json`

2) Using the following code:

```
public static IConfiguration InitConfiguration()
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json")
        .Build();
        return config;
}
```

But that returns this error:

> The configuration file 'appsettings.test.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Workspace\my_project\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\appsettings.test.json'.

I'd rather not put this file deeply nested into the `bin` folder. Is there some other way I can handle this?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Here's the big picture::

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Shared;
using Xunit;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using BusinessLogic;
using DataAccess.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public class Customers
    {
        private readonly IOptions<Configurations> _configurations;

        public Customers()
        {
            try
            {
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json")
                    .Build();

                 var config = InitConfiguration();
                 var clientId = config["Configutrations"]

                 _configurations = ??? // Still not sure how to do this.  Error before this point.

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var m = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        // all of the actual tests
}
```

The error happens on this line:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the properties of the `appsettings.test.json` file, I had to set the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if Newer`

[image]

Reference: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Feb/18/Accessing-Configuration-in-NET-Core-Test-Projects