# Read Appsettings in test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have a test method that while executing calls a method in the class which has the following line

```
_configuration.GetValue<string>("Root:Child");
```

The class has `IConfiguration` injected so this works fine in normal execution.

But it fails when the test method is executed

Edit 1: Test Class - complete

```
public class MyClassTest
{
 private AutoMocker mock;
 private Mock<IMyClient> client;
 private IMyClass testobj;

 public void Initialize()
 {
     mock = new AutoMocker();
     myRepo = mock.GetMock<IMyRepo>();
     client = mock.GetMock<IMyClient>();
     testobj = mock.CreateInstance<MyClass>();
 }

 public async Task testMethod()
 {
     var result = testobj.MyUnitTestMethod();
     // Assert
 }
```

MyClass

```
public class MyClass:IMyClass
{
 private readonly IMyClient _myClient;
 private readonly IConfiguration _config;
 
 //constructor
 public MyClass(IMyClient myClient, IConfiguration config)
 {
 }
 private async Task<MyEntity> MyMethod()
 {
  //some operation
  _config.GetValue<string>("Root:Child");
  //some operation
 }
}
```

I am trying to ensure when `MyUnitTestMethod` is called and in the flow when it reaches the `MyClass` method that has the line to read appsettings value (Root :Child) should get the value and not end up in error.

I tried adding a new config json in root test project and follow [Configurations in Core xUnit Test Project: The configuration file 'appsettings.test.json' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783736/configurations-in-core-xunit-test-project-the-configuration-file-appsettings-t)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock IConfiguration.GetValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794219/how-to-mock-iconfiguration-getvalue)

Comment: If I do it in Initialize method I can see the value. But soon as it goes to MyClass (testobj = mock.CreateInstance<MyClass>();) I do not see he value and when it comes to the test method and makes the call again it fails with object reference error.

Comment: I think I am missing how to make it available when it does a create instance call

Comment: Please add your entire test class to the question

Comment: Made the changes in question, hopefully that helps

Comment: That code will not compile. What is `_configuration`?

Comment: Apologies @Jocke corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Jocke on the constructor having two params unused, I assume you missed or thought it is not very relevant.

But here is what worked for me, I am updating your example:

```
public class MyClassTest
{
 private AutoMocker mock;
 private Mock<IMyClient> client;
 private IMyClass testobj;
 private Mock<IConfiguration> config; 

 public void Initialize()
 {
     mock = new AutoMocker();
     myRepo = mock.GetMock<IMyRepo>();
     client = mock.GetMock<IMyClient>();
     config = mocker.GetMock<IConfiguration>();
     config.Setup(x => x["Root:Child"]).Returns("ValueofChildAppSetting");
     testobj = mock.CreateInstance<MyClass>();
 }

 public async Task testMethod()
 {
     var result = testobj.MyUnitTestMethod();
     // Assert
 }
```

```
public class MyClass:IMyClass
{
 private readonly IMyClient _myClient;
 private readonly IConfiguration _config;
 
 //constructor
 public MyClass(IMyClient myClient, IConfiguration config)
 {
 }
 private async Task<MyEntity> MyMethod()
 {
  //some operation
  _config["Root:Child"];
  //some operation
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to read a .json file from disk for unit tests. Best practice is to avoid dependencies of any kind over network and on disk i/o during unit testing.

Instead you should mock these dependencies. You can use `Moq` to mock IConfiguration. It looks like you have tried that, but I think there is a missing statement in you constructor - you take in two parameter but you don't use them

```
 //constructor
 public MyClass(IMyClient myClient, IConfiguration config)
 {
 }
```

Here is one small, working, implementation of a class that is dependent on IConfiguration with a unit test passing in a mock.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Moq;

namespace TestProject2
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public MyClass(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public string Foo()
        {
            return _config.GetValue<string>("Root:Child");
        }
    }

    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Mock<IConfigurationSection> mockSection = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
            mockSection.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("from-unit-test");

            Mock<IConfiguration> mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
            mockConfig.Setup(x => x.GetSection("Root:Child")).Returns(mockSection.Object);

            var underTest = new MyClass(mockConfig.Object);
            Assert.Equal("from-unit-test", underTest.Foo());
        }
    }
}
```