# How do I get values from a json configuration file on c# using ConfigurationBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to get a path url from the following `notificatorConfig.json` file:

```
{
  "UserNotificatorConfig": {
    "URL": "http://localhost:8001",
    "BasePath": "/send-message/android"
  }
}
```

Using a `ConfigurationBuilder()` as follows:

```
public async Task Send(string message)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                           .AddJsonFile("notificatorConfig.json", true)
                           .Build();

    var url = config.GetSection("UserNotificatorConfig:URL").Value;
    var basePath = config.GetSection("UserNotificatorConfig:BasePath").Value;

    await _rest.PostAsync<Notification>(url, basePath, message);
}
```

Both my `json` file and the file where my `Send()` method is located, are in the same folder.

But every time I try to debug this method on unit tests I get `null` values for both parameters `url` and `basePath`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code looks a bit off to me. Building the configuration is something that's done in startup. Why are you trying to build it in some method during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("notificatorConfig.json", true)
    .Build();
```

And, as @Dennis1679 said, you should build configuration in startup.

**Edit**:

If this doesn't help, access `Value` inside `Section` this way:

```
var userNotificatorConfig = config.GetSection("UserNotificatorConfig");
var url = userNotificatorConfig.GetValue<string>("URL");
var basePath = userNotificatorConfig.GetValue<string>("BasePath");
```

Instead of this way:

```
var url = config.GetSection("UserNotificatorConfig:URL").Value;
var basePath = config.GetSection("UserNotificatorConfig:BasePath").Value;
```

Comment: No game, when I do this `GetCurrentDirectory()` returns my tests directory and not the one where my `json` is located.

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791634/read-appsettings-json-values-in-net-core-test-project. There is a specific issue about using `GetCurrentDirectory()` on a  test project, it is recommended that I keep a copy of my `json` file in the test project. I see a big issue here as I would have to assure equality in two different `json` files.

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674857/should-i-use-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-or-system-environment-current. *I see a big issue here as I would have to assure equality in two different json files.* I agree with you, however, it is a valid everyday solution.

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt I've added another way of accessing `Value`s in `UserNotificatorConfig` section, if previous solution doesn't help.