# App.config key values are not being found using when referenced with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Tags: c#, visual-studio

On Visual Studio Community 2017 V15.9.19 I created a new .Net Core NUnit test project, I added a Nuget package for system.configuration.configurationManager and created a App.config file within the same project.

The app.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="browser" value ="chrome"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I've tried referencing a key value using the below test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void GetConfigValue()
        {
            string setting = "browser";

            string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[setting];
            string b = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).AppSettings.Settings[setting].Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"a returns: { a } \nb returns: { b }");
        }
    }
}
```

This gives an output of:

a returns:
b returns: chrome

This is because a is null.
I've referenced keys using the a method previously I have no idea why I'm not able to currently.

Is there a setting or anything in Visual Studio which causes this as it was happening on another project so I tried making a new solution and project and it's happening there as well.

I can work around the issue using method b but I'm trying to fix my setup so I can reference keys in the config normally again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using app.config in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034007/using-app-config-in-net-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core uses appsettings.json instead of app.config by default. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034007/using-app-config-in-net-core) is another post on how to use an app.config instead, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791634/read-appsettings-json-values-in-net-core-test-project) is a post on using appsettings.json values in a test project.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much I was looking at it for ages. 
The project it worked on was .net framework rather than .net core which was totally the issue, didn't realise the config file behaved differently.

Comment: Honestly, I didn’t either until I just read about it. Just recently started working in .NET Core. Glad I could help. Rep appreciated.